# How to display image from API in React Native?

Tags: image, api, react-native

I am building a react native app using crna/expo. I want to display an image that already uploaded from API. Since the image is uploaded, I need to use require instead of uri as a source. But I failed to call the image when I put this code:

```
 <Image source={{require('this.state.user.picture')}} style={{ width: 75, height: 75, borderRadius: 37.5 }} />
```

Also when I changed it to uri, it didn't show anything either.... (not error tho)

```
<Image source={{uri:this.state.user.picture}} style={{ width: 75, height: 75, borderRadius: 37.5 }} />
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide more info? (like code and api response, it would help.)

Comment: I think you have to use `uri`, you dont have the image to use `require`. Can you provide us how it's looking your  `this.state.user.picture` ?

Comment: @tajammul1996 @oma thank you so much for your comments.. i tried to console.log the `this.state.user.picture` to know what's inside and it's only giving me the `picturename.jpg`

Comment: and what is the `typeof` that `picturename.jpg` ?

Answer (score 2):

If your answer is a `data` type image, you have to do like this:

```
// include at least width and height!
<Image
  style={{
    width: 51,
    height: 51,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  }}
  source={{
    uri:
      'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
  }}
/>
```

changing the `uri` with your `this.state.user.picture`

Comment: I think this is not the problem? because I got another error saying `undefined is not an object` after i changed it to `this.state.user.picture`

Answer (score 2):

Use `` for call images from variables

```
<Image style={{ width: 50, height: 200 }} 
        source={{ uri: `${item.image}` }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

what I suggest is that modify type according to some condition for eg.

note: **require need d local path of image and uri require http link**

```
let image = {uri:this.state.user.picture}; 

if(something){
 image = require('../../demo.jpg');
}

<Image source={image} style={{ width: 75, height: 75, borderRadius: 37.5 }} />
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have tried your suggestion and I got this error `calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found require('../api/assets/'+this.state.user.picture)` I think the path is wrong, i dont know which one is correct..

Comment: you need to confirm the path is correct with image name

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using double curly braces, when you only need **one pair**.

Try like that:

```
 <Image source={require('this.state.user.picture')} style={{ width: 75, height: 75, borderRadius: 37.5 }} />
```

Remember that the double curly braces are just an object literal inlined in the prop value.

Comment: thanks for your comment.. but when I changed it, it giving me another error.. `calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found require(this.state.user.picture)` I think the local path is still incorrect..

Comment: As i have heard of, react's require() only uses static url not variables. So instead of putting "this.state.user.picture" in your require, use a condition where you choose your images between a static urls.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same behavior. Just adding a `width` and `height` to the image worked for me.